# How to change the orientation of a list in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have three lists as follows.

```
mylist = [["sensor9", [[0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8], [0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]]], 
      ["sensor12", [[10.6, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9], [10.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]]]]

columns = ['score_1', 'score_2']
years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
```

I want to change the orientation of `mylist` as follows using `columns` as the headings and `years` for each element in `mylist`. More specifically, my final output should look as follows.

```
id, sensor, time, score_1, score_2
0, sensor9, 2001, 0.5, 0.5
0, sensor9, 2002, 0.3, 0.6
0, sensor9, 2003, 0.8, 0.8
0, sensor9, 2004, 0.9, 0.9
0, sensor9, 2005, 0.8, 0.9
1, sensor12, 2001, 0.6, 0.6
1, sensor12, 2002, 0.5, 0.9
1, sensor12, 2003, 0.9, 0.8
1, sensor12, 2004, 1.0, 0.8
1, sensor12, 2005, 0.9, 0.8
```

Dataframe that describes the id of the above dataframe

```
id, sensor
0, sensor9
1, sensor12
```

I was trying to do this with `DataFrame.from_dict` in pandas. However, I am not sure how to change the orientation of the `mylist` and align it with the `years` in pandas. Is it possible to do this?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: @CodeDifferent - I think it is typo, so changed in sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension for generate `DataFrame` for second values of lists (nested lists) with transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together and last create new column `id` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for first position:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[0,1],
                    'sensor':['sensor9','sensor12']})

mylist = [["sensor9",  [[0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8], [0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]]], 
          ["sensor12", [[10.6, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9], [10.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]]]]

columns = ['score_1', 'score_2']
years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]

L = [pd.DataFrame(x[1], index=columns, columns=years).T for x in mylist]

df = pd.concat(L, keys=[x[0] for x in mylist]).rename_axis(('sensor','time')).reset_index()
df.insert(0, 'id', df['sensor'].map(df1.set_index('sensor')['id']))
print (df)

   id    sensor  time  score_1  score_2
0   0   sensor9  2001      0.5      0.5
1   0   sensor9  2002      0.3      0.6
2   0   sensor9  2003      0.8      0.8
3   0   sensor9  2004      0.9      0.9
4   0   sensor9  2005      0.8      0.9
5   1  sensor12  2001     10.6     10.6
6   1  sensor12  2002      0.5      0.9
7   1  sensor12  2003      0.9      0.8
8   1  sensor12  2004      1.0      0.8
9   1  sensor12  2005      0.9      0.8
```

EDIT:

```
mylist = [["sensor9",  [[0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 0.8], [0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]]], 
          ["sensor12", [[10.6, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0, 0.9], [10.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8]]]]

columns = ['score_1', 'score_2']
years = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]

L = [pd.DataFrame(x[1], index=columns, columns=years).T for x in mylist]

df = pd.concat(L, keys=[x[0] for x in mylist]).rename_axis(('sensor','time')).reset_index()
df.insert(0, 'id', pd.factorize(df['sensor'])[0])
print (df)
   id    sensor  time  score_1  score_2
0   0   sensor9  2001      0.5      0.5
1   0   sensor9  2002      0.3      0.6
2   0   sensor9  2003      0.8      0.8
3   0   sensor9  2004      0.9      0.9
4   0   sensor9  2005      0.8      0.9
5   1  sensor12  2001     10.6     10.6
6   1  sensor12  2002      0.5      0.9
7   1  sensor12  2003      0.9      0.8
8   1  sensor12  2004      1.0      0.8
9   1  sensor12  2005      0.9      0.8
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the great answer. However, I also want to create `df1` in your code using `mylist`. It would be really great if you could tell me how to do that. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: I tried it. But I get an error saying `KeyError: 'Column not found: id'`. I want to assign ids starting from 0 to all the sensors in `mylist`. Looking forward to hearing from you :)

Comment: I tried it. However, the IDs assigned are not correct. I have attached my output in the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pqGXX2bEnIxY4Kz6B7LdyzIgPz7_G6r6/view?usp=sharing Please let me know how to fix this issue :)

Comment: sorry, not tested yet, so use `pd.factorize(df['sensor'])[0]`